# Google's Oauth IP Address range

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

Hi Is there an IP address range for Google's OAuth login (Social login)?

I have an internal application with a social login enabled (GitHub and Google). I have got the list of GitHub IP addresses from its metadata API (https://api.github.com/meta). Is there any API or list of IP address ranges that I can use for whitelisting the firewall?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The list of IP addresses would only be useful for egress firewall rules unless you are trying to authorize redirect callbacks. Edit your post to clearly define the problem. Otherwise, you will need to support Google's IP address range which opens you up to lots more than just OAuth which is also a risk: https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json

Comment: Hey @JohnHanley we are not blocking any egress connection and its open to the world. I am trying to open the ingress connection only for Google's oauth IP ranges (example: I have whitelisted the Github oauth IP address range for incoming traffic ).

Comment: Then how will clients start the OAuth Flow? Google OAuth is started in the user's browser and must interact with your backend (in most cases). Again, define what you are trying to accomplish. Note: by opening Google IP addresses, you are also allowing connections from services running with those IP addresses. Based on your post, you are not correctly implementing security and are creating a brittle environment for your application. OAuth has several protection mechanisms, but IP address filtering is not one of them.

Comment: @JohnHanley as i mentioned in the above post, my application is an internal application with no external users. All the end users have a VPN connection. So now I will enable ingress from Google OAuth and my VPN server IP.

Comment: Then to answer your question about `IP address range for Google's OAuth login`. AFAIK there is no published IP address list that only includes IP addresses used by Google's public authentication servers and no other services. Even if there was one, I would not recommend using it for firewall control of OAuth connections.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for your quick response. May I know why you wouldn't recommend this approach? also, will you open your firewall to the world if it is an internal application?

Comment: The first reason is how do you manage the IP address list? Google adds more servers, your service becomes unreliable (breaks). In general, relying upon IP addresses for security provides false security. Take the time to learn how OAuth is implemented and how to secure authorization services. I rarely use IP based firewalls to secure services. There are better strategies to implement strong security. Tip: for an internal application, you should not expose it to the Internet at all. That means breaking services into layers.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, accepted the Robina Mirbahar's Answer as it gives the list of IP address of OAuth.

Comment: No, it does it. That link is a list of all Google IP addresses and is not limited to OAuth servers. For example, my Google Compute Engine VM is within the Google block `34.64.0.0/10` which is on that list. That means you would be allowing anyone with a Google IP address into your security configuration. A hacker could spin up a Google Cloud VM and get through your whitelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has published a list of IP address ranges that can be used to whitelist for OAuth login. The IP ranges can be found in Google's official documentation, which can be accessed by following the link [IP address ranges](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json)

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: Hey Robin Your link is giving 404 please check once

Comment: I don't see any listed IP address here instead scopes available @RobinaMirbahar